# How to get url from popup?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to get url from opened popup. I tried already `window.location.href`. It is not working. When write `console.log(window.location.href)` there is `unreadeable` printed. How can I get `url` from popup in `React.js`

```
var newWindow = window.open("http://www.google.com/", "Code",
     'scrollbars=yes, width=' + 800 + ', height=' + 640 + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);
```

Error is

> ""react-dom.development.js:289 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame
>   with origin "http://localhost:3000" from accessing a cross-origin
>   frame.""

Comment: If the origin is different you cannot access it, otherwise you can access it via `newWindow.location.href`

Comment: The only ways to bypass the same origin policy would involve cooperation from the third party.

Answer (score 2):

**Try this**

`popupWindow.location.href` **OR** `newWindow.location.href`

If the popup is from a third party, you will not be allowed to inspect
 the popup location.href

The only ways to bypass the same origin policy would involve
 cooperation from the third party.

Comment: As I said before, I tried already location.href. It is not working. Error is ""react-dom.development.js:289 Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://localhost:3000" from accessing a cross-origin frame.""

Comment: So origin is different you cannot access it.

Comment: The only ways to bypass the same origin policy would involve cooperation from the third party.

Answer (score 0):

```
// basic XSS Payloads

javascript:alert(document.domain);

"><script>alert(document.domain);

//or

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML =
"Page location is " + window.location.href;
```